# What is the meaning of saying following: Let $P$ be a finitely presented $A[X]$ module. Suppose $P$ is extended from $A$?

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

What is the meaning of saying following:

> Let $P$ be a finitely presented $A[X]$ module. Suppose $P$ is extended from $A$?

I've not seen the above terminology.Could anyone please explain?

Comment: Please, add some more context.

Comment: @egreg: Please see Theorem $1$ [here](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/7680E36F104BCD582614B7F401C22365/S1865243313000172a.pdf/quillens_solution_of_serres_problem.pdf)

Comment: Maybe you have access to the full text; not everybody has.

Comment: @egreg: Oh i see,btw the title of the paper is "Quillen's solution of Serre's problem"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means $P$ is obtained from some $A$-module  by extension of scalars, i.e. there exists an $A$-module $M$ such that
$$P\simeq M\otimes_A A[X]\enspace\text{as $A[X]$-modules.}$$

Comment: Is it somehow related with projective modules?

Comment: Not  directly. Do you have something in mind?

Comment: Not really,i was asking because the above terminology is used is a paper  titled "Quille's solution of Serre's problem" and the aim of the paper is to prove that projective modules over polynomial rings are free.

Comment: I see: Quillen-Suslin's theorem, which proves Serre's conjecture (acttually one of Serre's conjectures).  This notion (a module being obtained by extension of scalars) is a general concept useful in many situations.

Comment: Sorry did you mean that it is more general than projective modules?

Comment: It's another notion. Neither more nor less general.