# Problem in understanding the Quillen's Theorem

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, projective-module

> **Theorem.** (Quillen) Let $P$ be a finitely presented $A[X]$-module. If for each maximal ideal $m \subset A$ the module $P_m$ is [extended from](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2215718/what-is-the-meaning-of-saying-following-let-p-be-a-finitely-presented-ax) $A_m$, then $P$ is extended from $A$.

**Proof:** (The proof is from paper titled *Quillen's solution of Serre's Problem*)

Consider the Quillen's sets $I= \{a \in A : P_a$ is extended from $A_a \}$. Now the author wants to show that $I$ is an ideal and $I$ is not contained in any maximal ideal and hence $1 \in I$ and we are done. Can someone explain me the idea of the proof to show $I$ is an ideal which is not contained in any maximal ideal? The proof is given in the paper but i don't really follow it. [Here](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/7680E36F104BCD582614B7F401C22365/S1865243313000172a.pdf/quillens_solution_of_serres_problem.pdf) is the link of the paper.

Comment: do you really expect someone to help you with this? the article is behind a paywall, so you should at least make a screen shot or copy the proof. you are the one that wants help, so you should make sure one can help you. also, since this is an expository article, you should be able to understand it.

Comment: $I$ is not contained in a maximal ideal follows from the assumptions. If $f\in I$ and $a\in A$, then $af\in I$ also follows easily. The harder part is if $f,g\in I$, then $f+g\in I$ and it is better to read his proof (it is clever, but can not be easily made better or simpler).

Comment: @Mohan: Is it obvious from assumptions that $I$ is not contained in a maximal ideal? I can't see it.

Comment: @Rüdiger: I have added the link of the paper.

Comment: @MathLover do you even realize that it is not publicy accessible? that's the whole point of what I said.

Comment: @Rüdiger: Thanks,i'll write down the given solution in my post!

Comment: @MathLover Yes, for any maximal ideal, the module is extended locally implies, using finite presentation, that there is an $a$ not in the maximal ideal such that $P_a$ is extended and thus $a\in I$.

Comment: @Mohan: Sorry how do you use finite presentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While easy as to how to use finite presentation, it is a bit long so I write it as an answer, though it is really not.

If $P$ is finitely presented as an $R=A[X]$ module, then so is $M[X]=M\otimes_A R$ where $M=P/XP$. The assumption says for a maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}\subset A$, you have $P_{\mathfrak{m}}\cong M[X]_{\mathfrak{m}}$. Using finite generation, clearing denominators, you get a map $P\to M[X]$ which is an isomorphism when you localize at $\mathfrak{m}$. The cokernel is zero when you localize at $\mathfrak{m}$ and the cokernel is finitely generated, so you can make it zero by inverting just one $a\not\in\mathfrak{m}$. The kernel is finitely generated since $P$ is finitely presented and again, you can make it zero by inverting a $b\not\in\mathfrak{m}$. Now, take $ab\not\in\mathfrak{m}$ and when you invert, both kernel and cokernel are zero. That is, $P_{ab}\cong M[X]_{ab}$.

The general fact used is for a finitely presented module $M$ over a ring $S$ and any module $N$ and a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}\subset S$, the natural map $(\mathrm{Hom}_S(M,N))_{\mathfrak{p}}\to \mathrm{Hom}_{S_{\mathfrak{p}}}(M_{\mathfrak{p}}, N_{\mathfrak{p}})$ is an isomorphism.